# DateTime Text with RightToleft Direction

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

I have a TextBlock with RightTolLeft FlowDirection:

```
  <TextBlock FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
      2018/2/1 12:15:50
  </TextBlock>
```

the problem is when UI renders this, the result is:

12:15:50 2018/2/1

but I want to show like this:

2018/2/1 12:15:50

there is any way to do that?

Comment: i dont think you can do it without changing the FlowDirection

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtTime" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>



public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    txtTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(" hh:mm:ss yyy/MM/dd ");
}
```